# React-redux get different state content with different action

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

My redux state was different when I go to the URL using this.props.history.push('login') and by going directly to the URL like http://localhost:19006/login

This is my Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    userData: null
};  

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if(action.type === "logout") {
        return initialState;
    } else if(action.type === "login"){
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            userData: action.payload
        });
    }
    return state;
};

export default rootReducer;
```

this is my Action.js

```
function logout() {
    return { type: "logout" }
}

function login(payload) {
    return { type: "login", payload }
}

export {logout, login};
```

this is my Store.jsx

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

import rootReducer from "./Reducer";

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

When I logged in, I store my userData using this
`store.dispatch(login(userData));`

But when I get redux state using this

```
var loggedIn = store.getState().userData;
console.log(loggedIn)
```

I get different results when I visit a URL using a different method

When I go to URL using this.props.history.push('login') the loggedIn variable will become my data (this is the correct one)

```
input
console.log(loggedIn)
output
{id: 1, name: "test"}
```

But I go to URL by paste the URL in the address bar the loggedIn variable will become null (this is the wrong one)
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLYBm.png)

```
input
console.log(loggedIn)
output
null
```

I don't have any idea why this would happen because literally I access the same URL but it gives a different result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page (from the URL bar) you are reloading the JavaScript context. Your store will be initialized as if it was new.

When you navigate trough History API, you are keeping the current JavaScript execution context, and your store is preserved in memory.

I see you're trying to persist your store on the local storage, but given your question, the persistence or the retrieving of the store (perhaps both) are failing.

Looking at [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) instructions, you should export as `default` a function, which returns an object, as such:

```
export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```